# PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: conn in

Tags: php

I've switched PHP version from 5 to 7 and the following error ocurred during connection to database.

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in /www/admin/Connection.php on line 14

1. Connection to database from command line is OK.
2. Connection to database from standard PHP code is OK as well.

   ```
   <?php
   class Connection
   {
   private static $conn;
   private $dbHost;
   private $dbUser;
   private $dbPass;
   private $dbName;
   public  $dbHandle;
   public $languages;

   public static function getConnection()
   {
           if($conn == null)
                   self::$conn = new Connection();
           return self::$conn;
   }

   protected function __construct()
   {
           $this->dbhost = BV_DB_HOST;
           $this->dbuser = BV_DB_USER;
           $this->dbpass = BV_DB_PASS;
           $this->dbname = BV_DB_NAME;
           $this->dbConnect();
   }

   public function dbConnect()
   {
           $this->dbHandle = mysqli_connect(BV_DB_HOST, BV_DB_USER, BV_DB_PASS);
           $tmp = mysqli_select_db($this->dbHandle, BV_DB_NAME);
           mysqli_query($this->dbHandle, "set names utf8");
           return $tmp;
   }

   public function languages()
   {
           return explode(";", BV_LANGS);
   }
   }
   ?>
   ```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'v changed condition in IF statement in getConnection() as follow.

```
if(!isset($conn))
```